# How to workback the projected sales value of each month given year sales value and monthly growth rate?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have a projected sales value (revenue) of a whole year (say $\$1,000,000$) and an envisaged monthly grow rate in sales of $15\%$.

I need to figure out what the sales value of each month from Jan to Dec look like, but I have been scratching my head for a day over this to no avail.

I would really appreciate any help!
Thanks.
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  If the increase is $15\%$ per month, you multiply January by $1.15$ to get February, then multiply again for March and so on.  You can use the formula for the sum of a finite series to get the total sales per dollar of January sales and divide into the full year number to get January.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks so much!